# How can I extract a domain name and insert it into a new Pandas column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with many columns, a subset of which is below:

```
df.info()

SQLDATE                  datetime64[ns]
SOURCEURL                object

df['SQLDATE', 'SOURCEURL'].sample()

SQLDATE    SOURCEURL
2017-01-08 http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/a/abc
2018-09-25 http://www.taiwannews.com.tw/a/news/123
2016-03-19 https://www.theguardian.com/a/2016/a/1/ab-bc
2015-12-12 https://nz.news.yahoo.com/world/a/3/a/
2017-04-07 https://www.thelocal.fr/2122/jkl
2019-02-21 http://today.az/news/a/123.html
2018-05-13 The BBC World News Report
```

I'm looking to create a column that can extract the domain name in order to get a new column that looks like this:

```
df.sample()

SQLDATE    SOURCEURL                               DOMAINNAME
2017-01-08 http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/a/abc   www.huffingtonpost.co.uk
2018-09-25 http://www.taiwannews.com.tw/a/news/123 www.taiwannews.com.tw
2016-03-19 https://www.theguardian.com/a...        www.theguardian.com
2015-12-12 https://nz.news.yahoo.com/world/a/3/a/  nz.news.yahoo.com
2017-04-07 https://www.thelocal.fr/2122/jkl        www.thelocal.fr
2019-02-21 http://today.az/news/a/123.html         today.az
2018-05-13 The BBC World News Report               The BBC World News Report
```

The dataframe does appear to be messy, where a few of the `SOURCEURL` fields simply contain text, no URL. I'd like to simply copy those values over into the `DOMAINNAME` column. I'm not too familiar with regular expressions, but this might be a case where it would apply.

Thanks for reviewing!

Comment: You sure you want domain name ? or subdomain + domain + suffix ?

Comment: I think I want the later if possible, i.e. - "nz.news.yahoo.com" instead of simply "yahoo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use positive lookbehind `?<=` and positive lookahead `?=` with regex, to get everything between `http://` OR `https://` and the first `/`:

```
m = df['SOURCEURL'].str.extract('(?<=http://)(.*?)(?=/)|(?<=https://)(.*?)(?=/)')
m = m[0].fillna(m[1]).fillna(df['SOURCEURL'])

df['DOMAINNAME'] = m
```

```
      SQLDATE                                     SOURCEURL                 DOMAINNAME
0  2017-01-08         http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/a/abc   www.huffingtonpost.co.uk
1  2018-09-25       http://www.taiwannews.com.tw/a/news/123      www.taiwannews.com.tw
2  2016-03-19  https://www.theguardian.com/a/2016/a/1/ab-bc        www.theguardian.com
3  2015-12-12        https://nz.news.yahoo.com/world/a/3/a/          nz.news.yahoo.com
4  2017-04-07              https://www.thelocal.fr/2122/jkl            www.thelocal.fr
5  2019-02-21               http://today.az/news/a/123.html                   today.az
6  2018-05-13                     The BBC World News Report  The BBC World News Report
```

Edit: to add on [mrzasa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56842060/9081267), we can also use `apply` with `urllib.parse.urlparse`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

df["DOMAIN"] = df["SOURCEURL"].apply(lambda row: urlparse(row).netloc)
```

```
      SQLDATE                                     SOURCEURL  \
0  2017-01-08         http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/a/abc   
1  2018-09-25       http://www.taiwannews.com.tw/a/news/123   
2  2016-03-19  https://www.theguardian.com/a/2016/a/1/ab-bc   
3  2015-12-12        https://nz.news.yahoo.com/world/a/3/a/   
4  2017-04-07              https://www.thelocal.fr/2122/jkl   
5  2019-02-21               http://today.az/news/a/123.html   
6  2018-05-13                     The BBC World News Report   

                     DOMAIN  
0  www.huffingtonpost.co.uk  
1     www.taiwannews.com.tw  
2       www.theguardian.com  
3         nz.news.yahoo.com  
4           www.thelocal.fr  
5                  today.az  
6
```

Answer (score 3):

This expression

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)
```

with this simple left boundary

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?
```

and this capturing group

```
([^\/]+)
```

might return our desired domain names.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ToBr9H/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

cell = # get cell from pandas df
domain = urlparse(cell).netloc
```